# Facebook authentication with querystring in redirect_uri

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to get my facebook authentication working with a redirect url on my website.

I've implemented the usual pattern where if a user tries to navigate to a page that is restricted he/she is redirected to the login page with a querystring.

Let's say the user tries to go to:
http://www.example.com/restrictedPage

The user will be redirected to:
http://www.example.com/Login?returnUrl=/restrictedPage

If the user successfully logs in, he/she is redirected to the page that was originally requested.

This works just fine when using my website's  own authentication, but I cannot make it work with the facebook authentication.

On the login page, in addition to the usual login form, I also have a link used to login with facebook. This is what it looks like in the same scenario as above (when the user tried to go to /restrictedPage):

*(I've inserted linebreaks to make it easier to read)*

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth
?client_id={client id}
&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fwww.example.com%2fLogin%2fLoginUsingFacebook%3freturnUrl%3d%2frestrictedPage
&scope=public_profile,email,user_friends
```

When the user has logged in to facebook he/she is redirected to the specified page (/Login/LoginUsingFacebook) as expected. Now I make a request to facebook to retrieve an access token:

```
/oauth/access_token
?client_id={client id}
&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fwww.example.com%2fLogin%2fLoginUsingFacebook%3freturnUrl%3d%2frestrictedPage
&client_secret={client secret}
&code={code}
```

This does not work and I recieve an error message from facebook:

*"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"*

It should be noted that if I do not have the returnUrl part (that is, if the user goes straight to the login page), it works fine. So I'm pretty sure that it is the returnUrl querystring that is the problem. But I don't understand what the problem is. The urls in the link and in the request are identical. Are querystrings not allowed by facebook?

(My web application is built using ASP.NET MVC 5 if that matters)